# COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT JOIN return too many rows

Tags: sql, collation

I am writing this query, the original query returns 272 rows

```
SELECT
i.InvoiceId
,i.AccountCode AS ClientAccountCode FROM 
vwInvoicesToSend i
    JOIN 
[SmartAdmin].dbo.Customers c ON i.AccountCode = c.AccountCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    JOIN 
InvoiceImages ii  ON i.invoiceid = ii.invoiceid WHERE 
i.BillRunId = 140 
    AND
c.BusinessGroup = 'xxxNZ'
```

I also have this subquery that returns 5795 rows

```
WITH base AS (
SELECT Email, MAX(AccountCode) AS AccountCode FROM [SMPro5Profile].dbo.vwPFD_0000001848 WHERE AccountCode IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Email,AccountCode)
```

When I try to perform an inner join between these two queries, I expect to see no more than 272 rows. But I got 1824 rows instead.

```
WITH base AS (SELECT Email, MAX(AccountCode) AS AccountCode FROM [SMPro5Profile].dbo.vwPFD_0000001848 WHERE AccountCode IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Email,AccountCode )  SELECT
i.InvoiceId
,i.AccountCode AS ClientAccountCode
--,base.AccountCode
--,base.[Email] FROM 
vwInvoicesToSend i
    JOIN 
[SmartAdmin].dbo.Customers c ON i.AccountCode = c.AccountCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    JOIN 
InvoiceImages ii  ON i.invoiceid = ii.invoiceid 
    INNER JOIN
base ON base.AccountCode = i.AccountCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT WHERE 
i.BillRunId = 140 
    AND
c.BusinessGroup = 'xxxNZ'
```

I suspect the anomaly is due to COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, as the two references columns have different collation definitions.

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue? Thank you :)

Comment: Check the group by on your CTE?

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of any query that includes the same column both within an aggregate *and* in the `GROUP BY` clause - so what's the thinking behind taking `MAX(AccountCode)` and also grouping on that column?

Comment: In ANSI SQL you add a collate clause to the invalid comparison, to force one collation to be used, e.g. "italian_column = french_column collate italian_collation".

Comment: Hi  Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the comments. This query was written to trouble shoot an existing messed up design and corrupted data.